# EntityManager is null in DAO using @PersistenceContext with transaction-type="JTA"

Tags: jpa, ejb, eclipselink, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I am facing issue to inject Entity Manager in DAO class, i searched lot of solutions but couldn't solve this issue.

I have EJB Bean Class

```
@Stateless(name = "MyBean", mappedName = "MyBean")
@Remote(MYRemoteBeanI.class)
public class MyBeanImpl implements MYRemoteBeanI {

@EJB
MyDAO dao; // This DAO gets injected. But entity manager inside this DAO is null

}
```

DAO class

```
@Stateless
public class MyDAO {

//This is not injecting, it will be always null
@PersistenceContext(unitName="MyPersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager; 

}
```

Persistence.xml as below

```
<persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>myDataSource</jta-data-source>
<mapping-file>META-INF/orm.xml</mapping-file>
<!-- Some managed classes -->
<!-- Some properties -->
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Pls assist me solving this issue. I am new to EJB world!

Comment: And how is instantiated `MyBeanImpl` ? It should be injected as well

Comment: Which App Server are you using? Are there any error messages?

Comment: MyBeanImpl is remote bean. it is instantiated in client application by using JNDI Service locator as below                          
JNDIServiceLocator serviceLocator=JNDIServiceLocator.getInstance();

Comment: I am using weblogic application server, there is no error logged related to data source or persistence unit. No DB related errors also. when i create Entity Manager manually in DAO then it works                                 EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyPersistenceUnit");
           entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

Comment: But i dont want to create it manually. I want it to be created by container and inject into my DAO

Answer (score 0):

Seems is not reading your *persistence-unit* from Persistence.xml. 
Where is the xml located?

Here is a working example in Jboss 7/Wildfly connecting to an Oracle DB.

```
@Stateless
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @EJB(name = "myDAO")
    private MyDAO segmentDTO;
}

@Local
public interface MyDAO {

}

@Stateless
public class MyDAOImpl implements MyDAO {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "exampleEM")
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="exampleEM" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS</jta-data-source>
        <!-- your entities -->

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```